# Azure Search Indexer Optimization, Notification

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am looking for **two** things from **Azure Search**.

1. I want to be notified by the Azure Search Service when the Indexer completes the process.
2. Is there a way I can optimize the performance of Indexer such that if it's completing in one hour now, can be completed in 30 minutes?

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. The way to achieve this is to query [indexer status API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/get-indexer-status). Also, please vote for this [UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/10095111-azure-search-alerts) and leave a comment with your use case.
2. The specific suggestions for performance optimization depend on the datasource you use, and whether the performance bottleneck is on the datasource side or on Azure Search side. If you share your service name and indexer name, we can take a look at the telemetry and provide more targeted advice.

Comment: how should i share the indexer and service name. can i do it over something other than stackoverflow?

Comment: Please email me at eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain